# Zephyr OS runtime memory usage

Tags: memory, runtime, zephyr-rtos

There is only a ram report to analyzing the Zephry application,
but it looks like there is no shell command or method to check the runtime memory usage on Zephyr OS,
Does anyone know how to check the runtime memory (heap and stacks) usage on Zephry OS?

kernel stacks
can only display the stacks state of kernel threads, with no memory heap-related information.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The `kernel stacks` command seems to print out all stacks the OS is aware of; even ones that your application begins so that should work for stack checking at runtime. As for heap checking, there is no builtin command available and making your own depends on which libc you are using. The minimal libc has uses a `sys_heap` under the hood which gives you access to `sys_heap_print_info` and `sys_heap_runtime_stats_get` (if you enable `CONFIG_SYS_HEAP_RUNTIME_STATS`) but getting a reference to the `sys_heap` might be difficult. For newlib, mallinfo` or `malloc_stats` might work.